# laravel delete sweetalert 1 javascript

Tags: laravel, post, sweetalert

my confirmation sweetalert didn't work for delete. but it already show the pop up function for sweetalert. yes button cant read my controller for delete the data.

form

```
<form action="{{url('/Admin/Page/Carousel/delete')}}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$datas->id}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete').click(
        function(e){
            var button = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure ?",
                text: "Data",
                type: "warning",
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'Delete!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if(result.value){
                    button.closest('form').submit();
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/Admin/Page/Carousel/delete','adminController@postdeleteCarousel');
```

Controller

```
function postdeleteCarousel(Request $req){
    $id = $req->input('id');

    Carousel::find($id)->delete();

    $req->session()->flash("pesan", "Delete Carousuel Success!");
    $req->session()->flash("title", "Delete Success!");
    $req->session()->flash("alert", "success");
    return redirect('/Admin/Page/carousel');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In blade file:

```
<form id="delete_form_{{ $datas->id  }}" action="{{url('/Admin/Page/Carousel/delete')}}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$datas->id}}">
    <button data-id="{{$datas->id}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

In js:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        swal({
            title: "Are you sure ?",
            text: "Data",
            type: "warning",
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Delete!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if(result.value){
                $(document).find('#delete_form_'+id).submit();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```